# How to use django-scheduler app in existing app

Tags: python, django, scheduler

I am looking for django apps to handle Task Calendar kind of event and django-schedule example project provides a sample project but I dont know how to map the my Task class (title & startTime) with the event class of django schedule. Documentation doesn't make it clear how can I do that? Will really apprciate if some pointers or steps can be provided here to use django-schedule app with an existing app

The solution here [Using the Django scheduler app with your own models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327121/using-the-django-scheduler-app-with-your-own-models) is present but I am not able to make much out of it. I am looking for some tutorial on how to hook django-scheduler to my own model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this good conversation on internet https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pinax-users/9NoRWjMdiyM and with as reference will explain the logic as below:

1. Assume your task class to be having startDateTime & endDateTime & Title
2. from schedule.models import Event, EventRelation, Calendar ( Coming from Schedule app)
3. Override the save method of Task object to create new event as below , modified the code provided in the link above to make it clearer
4. The code looks for a existing Calendar and attaches the event to it which is linked to the Task object via relationship
5. Tried the code below to extend the Project-Sample app provided with the source and it worked fine

   ```
   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
       new_task = False
       if not self.id:
           new_task = True
       super(Task, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
       end = self.startDateTime + timedelta(minutes=24*60)
       title = "This is test Task"
       if new_task:
           event = Event(start=self.startDateTime, end=end,title=title,
                     description=self.description)
           event.save()
           rel = EventRelation.objects.create_relation(event, self)
           rel.save()
           try:
               cal = Calendar.objects.get(pk=1)
           except Calendar.DoesNotExist:
               cal = Calendar(name="Community Calendar")
               cal.save()
           cal.events.add(event)
       else:
           event = Event.objects.get_for_object(self)[0]
           event.start = self.startDateTime
           event.end = end
           event.title = title
           event.description = self.description
           event.save()
   ```

Still have to search for extending the Click functionality on the Calendar event which currently gives a text box , how to customize that with a hyper link remains to be seen but the code above answers the question and part of the problem