# Installing Django-scheduler

Tags: django

Im probably going going to get -rep for this but my fuse is about to blow, can someone please specify the steps of importing a new package. Im trying to install django-scheduler iv got so far but then im looking back and asking myself questions have i done this right? i have not found any information on  where to put the files(setup.py) where to put the actual files of the calendar(scheduler) and how to Properly install packages. I'm finding a lot of different approaches online and i'm trying everything i find.

Iv followed the installation steps on https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-scheduler but i get stuck at npm,

I'v tried to look for it and install it i get numerous errors i just wanted someone to clarify what I'm actually suppose to be doing here. please my head hurts.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using pip:

```
pip install django-scheduler
```

Comment: i have done this so many times, what after this? im a suppose to download the package from github and put them files somewhere

Comment: If you are using linux(ubuntu in my opinion) you can use django-scheduler after installing it with pip. I suppose its works with other OS`s. Did you check scheduler in your IDE?

Comment: pip already installed django-scheduler after entering the following command.

Comment: Iv just installed it on a fresh project it says Requirents already satisfied, now what? how do i use it? do i need to copy some files over to the new project?

Comment: Alright, all I know is how to install this. No idea how to use this :)

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239783/how-to-use-django-scheduler-app-in-existing-app